# Is it safe to hold a std::lock_guard in the destructor?

Tags: c++, multithreading, destructor

I'm trying to decide if the following code is safe, or if it is UB and only happens to work well in this case (run it [here](https://repl.it/repls/ConcernedElderlyDevice)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

struct Foo
{
  std::mutex mutex;
  ~Foo()
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
  }
};

int main() 
{
  {
    Foo foo;
  }
  std::cout << "everything seems to work fine...?" << std::endl;
}
```

Specifically, are we guaranteed anywhere that local variables defined inside the destructor will be destructed before the member variables are?

I found the following from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor), but it doesn't seem to fully answer my question:

> ### Destruction sequence
>
> For both user-defined or implicitly-defined destructors, after the body of the destructor is executed, the compiler calls the destructors for all non-static non-variant members of the class, in reverse order of declaration, then it calls the destructors of all direct non-virtual base classes in reverse order of construction (which in turn call the destructors of their members and their base classes, etc), and then, if this object is of most-derived class, it calls the destructors of all virtual bases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the standard in [class.dtor]/9,

> After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any automatic objects allocated within the body, a
>   destructor for class `X` calls the destructors for `X`’s direct non-variant non-static data members, the destructors
>   for `X`’s non-virtual direct base classes and, if `X` is the type of the most derived class (15.6.2), its destructor
>   calls the destructors for `X`’s virtual base classes. ...

This answers your question in the affirmative.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor's body is executed before any member is destructed. In this sense it's safe.

But prior to the question if it is safe the question if there is any sensible use case to hold the mutex in the destructor (as well as the constructor) must be asked.

Only one thread can construct or destruct an object. This must be assured by a mutex **outside** of the object, e.g. at construction in the factory or at destruction in the shared pointer.

Comment: And perhaps that's exactly what this class is doing - managing a subobject that requires synchronisation.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: A subobject is never accessed except from its parent object. So it is not needed to hold the object's mutex because it must be assured that at constructrion or desctruction only one thread does access the object.

Comment: The subobject could have been externally exposed and, even if it weren't, holding a mutex could be important for managing the shutdown of the encapsulated subobject.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Accessing an exposed subobject that is protected by a mutex that is being destructed is suspicious. From a practical stand point of view I would reject it on a code review.

Comment: It isn't being destructed. Not yet.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: If another thread would access the mutex during execution of the the body of the destructor (while the mutex is still valid) how could another thread be prevented from acccessing the mutex when it is destructed?

Comment: Because if the thread is owned by the subobject then you are currently performing cleanup operations and telling it to close that thread and cease operation. That would literally be the purpose of this code.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: In a clean design this communication would be done via a mutex of the subobject: The subobject would have a state that is finally going to _Terminated_. This state would be protected by the subobject's mutex.

Comment: And if two subobjects, that use threading, share access to a third subobject? That needs protection. I reckon you're overthinking it. A lock in a destructor is not mad.

Comment: Not, you don't want a global mutex. The mutex should be owned by the thing that's responsible for the protected objects.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Then the third object would have a mutex to protect its data. If you for some reason want one global mutex for everything you can do it. But then this global mutex is certainly wrongly located in an object that is destructed. You would use a mutex at global scope.
I don't overthink things I just keep things simple and avoid .suspicious code.

Comment: Again, nobody's suggesting a "global mutex". But a thing is responsible for protecting the things it owns.

Comment: If the object would have a method shutdown that takes the mutex and that shutdown method is also called from the desctructor (without taking the mutex) then ok. 
And in general it should be avoided that a subobject accesses the parent's members or calls the parent's methods. If this is done from the subobjects destructors it gets even more dangerous.